# Why did Python3 execute a piece of commented-out code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After a bit over 8 years of using Python I've run today into issue with Python 3.8: it executed code that I commented out.

I was able to interrupt it as it was going through code path that should have been blocked by the comment to get this screenshot:

[image]

As the function names indicate, the operation in question is somewhat time-consuming to rollback and I would love to know what happened to avoid dealing with that in the future.

My current best explanation is that since the code is run on a remote machine for whatever reason the commenting out did not go through when the code started, but did for the stack trace.

Does anyone had a similar experience or have an idea of what might have happened?

Comment: Did you double-check that it's actually a regular `#` and not a similar Unicode character like `U+FF03 ＃ FULLWIDTH NUMBER SIGN` or `U+FE5F ﹟ SMALL NUMBER SIGN`? Probably not the issue, but throwing it out there just in case

Comment: The most likeliest explanation is that the trace is wrong. The likeliest reason for that is that there's a discrepancy between the code in the file and the code that's getting executed, e.g. because there's a .pyc file or other `__pycache__` which is actually being executed. The trace is just created from the readable .py file.

Comment: @jdaz - would doubt that - I've been using the same shortcut to comment out code for over 5 years now and even today it was still working well in other parts of the code

Comment: Can you supply any evidence that the commented line was executed?  The stack trace *might* be just displaying the line although not executed.  (Treading lightly with the last statement).

Comment: I am fairly sure that the stack trace is populated when the error occurs, not when the code is first interpreted, so if you have one file, run it, then replace its contents while it is still running (ie a delayed network-save) you will end up with a stack trace that isn't representative of the code that was run.

Comment: As an aside ... `destroy_db` ... might be a bit heavy handed, eh?  ;-)

Comment: @deceze: I was thinking about the same thing. Any idea of how to clear them before the execution to force recompilation from text files? Maybe a command line python option?

Comment: @WillRichardson - that's what I suspect happened as well. Any idea how to prevent that in the future?

Comment: @S3DEV - I mean since the database is can be rebuild from scratch in about an hour from text files and need to be updated regularly from those files, `destroy_db` actually is a good name for what it does :) As for the delay between execution and stack trace - that's what I myself suspect happened - any way to prevent it that you would know of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I confirmed my hypothesis from the comments, with a file like:

```py
import time

def dont_run():
  raise Exception("oh no i ran it")

time.sleep(10)

dont_run()
```

I saved that file, and ran it. While it was running I commented out the last line and re-saved the file, I then got this error:

```sh
$ py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    # dont_run()
  File "main.py", line 6, in dont_run
    raise Exception("oh no i ran it")
Exception: oh no i ran it
```

So I think what must have happened here is that you ran the file before the file was saved to disk (perhaps a race between two network requests and you got unlucky).

Comment: Yup - so the sending data to the remote server just lagged. Any idea as to how the requests can be ordered? Except for waiting a bit between editing and starting a run?

Comment: Depends on what you're using to edit and run the files, most editors have a saving/saved status indicator which you can use to determine when the change has been committed. I'd just edit in vim on the remote server, so I'm probably not the best person to ask.

Comment: Ok, Pycharm seems to have an option in Settings | General | Editor Tabs | Mark modified (*). I've turned that on - let's hope it goes through all right!

Comment: I've seen this fairly often when I run tests repeatedly in one window using [`watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) while editing in another window. When it's throwing errors and I fix one, the code in the traceback changes first, then in the next run the test passes.